# Kivy add widget from thread

Tags: python, multithreading, kivy

I am trying to add a widget to the screen via a thread. This is the function I am calling from within the thread:

```
@mainthread
def add_message(self, text):
    message_lab = Label(text=text, markup=True)
    message_lab.text_size = message_lab.width, None

    self.add_widget(message_lab)
```

When I run this, I can see that the widget has been added into the children variable of the layout, but it does not show up. When I tried to make a small segment of code, it worked. However, I still don't know what the problem is. Any help I could get would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please post a minimal runnable example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I do not know why, but when I try to make a minimal reproducible example, the code works they way I want to, but this code doesn't work

Comment: @Pokechu48 So your MRE is not an MRE, by reducing it you are probably eliminating the cause of the error. If you do not provide the MRE then your question is off-topic so it could be closed.

Comment: Sorry about that. I found out the problem in my code. Thank you for the help!